# Getting the count of column by joinning the tables

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I have below three tables which are joined among themselves. The tables names are

- ioa_invoice_line
- ioa_invoice_line_notes
- IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP

An image is attached which will graphically shows you the relationship. I am trying to get the count of `inv_line_note_id` from the `IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP` table with respect to each id column in the `ioa_invoice_line` table. Please advise how to get the count of column `inv_line_note_id` of `IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP` table with context to id column in the `ioa_invoice_line` table .

As advised I have added sample data:

**IOA_INVOICE_LINE**:

```
ID             VERSION
1234            Abc
```

**IOA_INVOICE_LINE_NOTES**:

```
ID       INLI_ID        NOTES
345      1234           Aqou
```

**INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP**:

```
ID      INV_LINE_NOTE_ID          ATTACHMENT
23            345                   rtfffr
24            345                   fhgygg
```

So as shown above that with respect to invoice_line, column id 1234 count of column `Attachment` of `inv_line_note_map` table is `2`

So please advise how can I count the value of column attachment of  `inv_line_note_map` table with respect to column id of the invoice line table and if there is no count then it should return `0`.

I have tried the below things but it is not the expected solution so please advise

```
select * from IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP where inv_line_note_id =66060
select * from ioa_invoice_line_notes where inli_id = 97750
select * from ioa_invoice_line where id = 97750 ;
```

Comment: Edit your question and include (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) attempt you have made to query the data.

Comment: @Gordon linoff. Thanks I have added the things as advise,  Please advise

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for a couple of outer joins and a call to the count() function.

```
select ioa_invoice_line.id, count(inv_line_note_map.attachment) as attachment_count
from ioa_invoice_line
     left outer join ioa_invoice_line_notes 
              on ioa_invoice_line.id = ioa_invoice_line_notes.inli_id
     left outer join inv_line_note_map 
              on ioa_invoice_line_notes.id = inv_line_note_map.id
group by ioa_invoice_line.id;
```

Comment: I think you've got a typo: group by should be on ioa_invoice_line.id not ioa_invoice_line_id

Comment: You are right - I made that typo when I was testing and I thought I fixed it. I will fix it in my reply now. Thanks!